# Small Detail in Folland Prop.2.12

Tags: measure-theory

> **2.12 Proposition.** *Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $(X,\overline{\mathcal{M}},\overline{\mu})$ be its completion. If $f$ is an $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$-measurable function on $X$, there is an $\mathcal{M}$-measurable function $g$ such that $f=g$ $\overline{\mu}$-almost everywhere.*
>
> *Proof.* This is obvious from the definition of $\overline{\mu}$, if $f=\chi_E$ where $E\in\overline{\mathcal{M}}$, and hence if $f$ is an $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$-measurable simple function. For the general case, choose a sequence $\{\phi_n\}$ of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$-measurable simple functions that converge pointwise to $f$ according to Theorem 2.10, and for each $n$ let $\psi_n$, be an $\mathcal{M}$-measurable simple function with $\psi_n=\phi_n$ except on a set $E_n\in\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ with $\overline{\mu}(E_n)=0$. Choose $N\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mu(N)=0$ and $N\supset\bigcup_1^\infty E_n$, and set $g=\lim \chi_{X\setminus N}\psi_n$ Then $g$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable by Corollary 2.9, and $g=f$ on $N^c$. $\square$

Just wondering for the characteristic function case, why does the statement hold.

I see that by definition of completion, we have $E= A \cup Z$, where $A \in M$ and $Z \subset N$  for some null set $N \in M$.

Let $g= \chi_ A$. I'm not sure why we have $f=g$ almost everywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: I think $E = A \cup Z$, where $A \in M$ and $Z \subset N$ for some null set $N \in M$

Comment: Thanks for having accepted my answer. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it too. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is:

> Consider $E\in \overline{\mathcal{M}}$ and $f= \chi_E$.  Then we have that
> $E= A \cup Z$, where $A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $Z \subseteq N$  for some null set $N \in \mathcal{M}$.
> Let $g= \chi_ A$. How to prove that  $f=g$ $\bar{\mu}-$almost everywhere.

Let $[f \neq g] =\{x \in X: f(x) \neq g(x)\}$. Note that $[f \neq g] \subseteq Z \subseteq N$. Since  $N \in \mathcal{M}$ and $\mu(N)=0$, any subset $C$ of $N$ is in $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ and $\bar{\mu}(C)=0$ . Since $[f \neq g] \subseteq N$, we have that $[f \neq g] \in \overline{\mathcal{M}}$ and $\bar{\mu}([f \neq g])=0$. So  $f=g$ $\bar{\mu}-$almost everywhere.