# Proving in detail proposition 2.12 of Folland

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(X, M,m)$ be a measure space and let $(X, \overline M ,\overline m)$ be its completion. If $f$ is an $\overline M$-measurable function on $X$, there is an $M$-measurable function $g$ such that $f=g\,\, \,  \overline m$-almost everywhere.

Some symbols have been changed for brevity. To prove the above theorem, the proof below considers three cases: $1)$ $f$ is an indicator function, $2): f$ is a simple function, and $3):f $ is neither of the types mentioned in $(1)$ or $(2)$.

**Case $1$: $f=1_E$ for some $E\in \overline M$.**

By the description of elements of $\overline M$, there exist $E'\in M, N\in M, H\subset N$ such that $m(N)=0$ and $E=E'\cup H.$

Consider $g:=1_{E'\cap N}$. Then note that $E'\cap N\subset N\implies E'\cap N\in \overline M$ and $\overline m(E'\cap N)=0$ as $\overline M$ is complete. For any $x\in (E'\cap N)^c= E'^c\cup N^c\subset E^c, g(x)=0=f(x)$. Hence, $f=g\,\,\, \overline m$ a.e. This proves case $1$.

**Case $2:f=\sum_{j\ge 1}^n c_j1_{E_j}$, where $c_j\ne 0, E_j\in \overline M$ for all $j\in \{1,2,...,n\}$**. The case is chosen as such because if all $c_j$'s were zero then $f=1_{\emptyset}$ and the result follows by case $1$. WLOG, assume that $E_j$'s partition $X$.

Consider $g=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j1_{E_j'\cap N_j}$, where the symbols on RHS are taken from case $1$ for $j$. Set $N=\cup_{j=1}^n (E_j\cap N_j)$ and note that for all $x\in N^c$, $g(x)=0=f(x)$. $\overline m(N)=0$. Hence $f=g$ a.e. (w.r.t. $\overline m$).

**Case $3:f$ can be approximated by simple functions $\phi_i\to f$ as $i\to \infty$.**

For each $n$, there exist $\psi_n=\phi_n$ a.e. (henceforth, a.e. is w.r.t. $\overline {m} ) $ ,$\overline m( E_n)=0$, where $\psi_n$ is $M$ measurable and $\overline M\ni E_n=E_n'\cup H_n\subset E_n'\cup N_n\in M$, where the notations have been taken from case $2$. Set $N=\cup_j N_j$ and define $g=\lim_n\psi_n 1_{N^c}$. Note that $\overline m(N)=0$ and $g$ is $M$ measurable. Note that for every $x\in N^c$, $g(x)=\lim \psi_n(x)=\lim_n\phi_n(x)=f(x)$. Hence, $f=g$ a.e.

Is the proof above correct? Thanks.

Comment: It seems fine. You can simplifying considerably by noticing that it is enough to consider $f\geq0$, and by recalling that if $f$ is $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$-measurable then there is a sequence of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$-measurable simple functions $s_n\nearrow f$. Then $f=\sum_n (s_n-s_{n-1})=\sum_ka_k\mathbb{1}_{A_k}$ where $A_k\in\overline{\mathcal{M}}$. Now use $B_k\subset A_k\subset C_k$ such that $B_k,C_k\in\mathcal{M}$ and $\mu(C_k\setminus B_k)=0$. The functions $f_B=\sum_ka_k\mathbb{1}_{B_k}$ and $f_C=\sum_ka_k\mathbb{1}_{C_k}$ are $\mathcal{M}$-measurable and equal to $f$ $\mu$-a.s.

Comment: @OliverDíaz: Thanks a lot for the review and comment :-).

Comment: I think it's incorrect. For $g$ you should use just the indicator of $E'$ not the indicator of $E'\cap N$. See here for example; https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4007771

Comment: Intuitively if $E=E'\cup N$ where $\mu(N)=0$ then if $f=\chi_E$ and $g=\chi_{E'}$ since $E$ is equal to $E'$ modulo a set of measure zero we would expect $f$ to be approximately $g$ but if $g=\chi_{E'\cap N}$ then $E'\cap N$ may be very different to the set $E$ since $N$ is measure theoretically small so you would not expect $f$ and $g$ to be equal.

Comment: @tail_recursion: Thanks for pointing that out.